# jquery mobile my action php page is not getting input file

Tags: php, jquery-mobile

hellow my this is my form in jquery mobile i also turbed off the data-ajax and define the enctype but still i am not getting my file in my action page

```
<form id="form_id"  action="action/cat-manag-add.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-ajax="false" method="post">
<label class="TSG-font" for="category_image">Category image:</label>
<input class="required" type="file" name="file" id="file" value="" >
<form>
```

this my action page getting all $_POST values but not getting the $_FILES

```
$title=$_POST['title'];
$description=$_POST['description'];
$file=$_FILES['file'];
```

kindly help me

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: besides your variables to POST/FILES assignment, I don't see anything else that handles it. Check for errors from the link I gave you above.

Comment: dear there is thew hole code i just gave an overview all code is running good but $file have nothing in it and i check my form array i am getting every value except the file

Answer (score 0):

Remove value="" in input type file.
And try var_dump($_FILES); check what is print in you action page